# std::tr1::bind() several compilation error

Tags: c++, mingw32

i try to use bound function but my code can't be compiled. I use Qt5.3.1 with MinGW 4.8.

my class :

```
class ProcessSearch : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ProcessSearch(QObject *parent = 0);
    void Search(const QString startDir, const QString destDir, QList<QString> wavList);

signals:
    void status(int);
    void statuslog(QString);

private:
    QString startDir, destDir;
    QList<QString> wavList;

};
```

i try to bind the Search method like this :

```
auto f = std::tr1::bind(&ProcessSearch::Search, std::tr1::placeholders::_1, pathDest, wavList);  
f(wavpathList.at(0));
```

But i have several errors when i try to built it .... The first error :

```
no match for call to '(std::tr1::_Mem_fn<void (ProcessSearch::*)(QString, QString, QList<QString>)>) (const QString&, QString&, QList<QString>&)'
```

where is my mistake ?  thx

Comment: A call like `ps.Search(s, d, l)` has **4** arguments, `ps`, `s`, `d` and `l`. You have only provided 3 arguments. Which `ProcessSearch` object do you expect the member function to be called on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need the instance of *ProcessSearch* during the bind.

```
std::tr1::bind(&ProcessSearch::Search, this, ... )
```

Note, think about using C++11 and you can easily express those connections with lambdas. Or at least consider *std::bind* (e.g., [CppReference] http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: Thank you. Indeed i need to instance my class ProcessSearch.

    std::tr1::bind(&ProcessSearch::Search, &proc, std::tr1::placeholders::_1, pathDest, wavList)

Comment: but generally, why do you want to use ´bind´ and immediately call ´f´?

Comment: In fact, i want work with QtConcurrent to get a multi-thread of my methode "Search". And when i built my code, i had a lot of error ...So i called "f" just to check.

Comment: Just a suggestion: I#m also using some functions from QtConcurrent and using mostly some dedicated class that encapsulates the behavior for each run instead of a function.